# Pulling data from ajax to change div on overlay

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, ajax

Can anyone help me understand what's wrong with my code.

I have 3 links, each with a data-action and a ID number.

When I click, nothing happens. It's not pulling the data from my ajax (action.php)

HTML CODE:

```
<style>
#overlay{ /* we set all of the properties for are overlay */
    height:80%;
    width:80%;
    margin:0 auto;
    background:white;
    color:black;
    padding:10px;
    position:absolute;
    top:5%;
    left:10%;
    z-index:1000;
    display:none;
    /* CSS 3 */
    -webkit-border-radius:10px;
    -moz-border-radius:10px;
    -o-border-radius:10px;
    border-radius:10px;
}

#mask{ /* create are mask */
    position:fixed;
    top:0;
    left:0;
    background:rgba(0,0,0,0.6);
    z-index:500;
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
    display:none;

}
/* use :target to look for a link to the overlay then we find are mask */
#overlay:target, #overlay:target + #mask{
    display:block;
    opacity:1;
}
.close{ /* to make a nice looking pure CSS3 close button */
    display:block;
    position:absolute;
    top:-20px;
    right:-20px;
    background:red;
    color:white;
    height:40px;
    width:40px;
    line-height:40px;
    font-size:35px;
    text-decoration:none;
    text-align:center;
    font-weight:bold;
    -webkit-border-radius:40px;
    -moz-border-radius:40px;
    -o-border-radius:40px;
    border-radius:40px;
}

.button{ /* open the overlay */
    padding:10px 5px;
    background:blue;
    color:white;
    text-decoration:none;
    display:inline-block;
    margin:20px;
    -webkit-border-radius:10px;
    -moz-border-radius:10px;
    -o-border-radius:10px;
    border-radius:10px;
}

#overlay-content { 
    color:red;
}
</style>


<a href="#" class="button" data-action="1">link 1</a>
<a href="#" class="button" data-action="2">link 2</a>
<a href="#" class="button" data-action="3">link 3</a>

<div id="overlay">
    <a href="#" class="close">&times;</a>
    <div id="overlay-content"></div>
</div>

<div id="mask" onclick="document.location='#';"></div>


<script type="text/javascript">
    $(".button").click(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();

        $.ajax(function(){
            url: "action.php",
            method: "get",
            data: {
                id: $(this).attr("data-action")
            }, 
            success: openOverlay(data)
        })
    });

    function openOverlay(html_content)
    {
        // Clear out the overlay-content
        $("#overlay-content").html("");

        // Add new stuff in
        $("#overlay-content").html(html_content);

        $("#overlay").css("display:block; opacity:1;");
        $("#mask").css("display:block; opacity:1;");
    }
</script>
```

AND HERE IS ACTION.PHP

```
if (isset($_GET['id'])) 
{
    $id = $_GET['id'];  

    $html = "This is a TEST...  ID = ".$id;

    echo $html;
    exit;
}
```

Comment: try `$('.button').on('click', function(){//your code here});`

Comment: @Theunis no, same thing. Nothing happens

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your script should be like this

```
$(".button").click(function(e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            $.ajax({
                    url: "action.php",
                    method: "get",
                    data: {
                    id: $(this).attr("data-action")
                    },
                    success: openOverlay

            });
        });
            function openOverlay(html_content)
            {
            // Clear out the overlay-content
            $("#overlay-content").html("");
            // Add new stuff in
            $("#overlay-content").html(html_content);
            function openOverlay(html_content)
        {
            alert(html_content);
        // Clear out the overlay-content
        $("#overlay-content").html("");
        // Add new stuff in
        $("#overlay-content").html(html_content);
        $("#overlay").css("display", 'block').css("opacity", '1');
        $("#mask").css("display", 'block').css("opacity", '1');
        }
            }
```

For close overlay

```
$('.close').on('click', function(e){
               $("#overlay").css("display", 'none').css("opacity", '0');
            $("#mask").css("display", 'none').css("opacity", '0'); 

            });
```

Comment: no changes.. .nothing opens up when I click the button

Comment: try to alert `html_content`

Comment: yes, if I alert, It pop up the correct string... So the problem is the display of the overlays from display:none; to display:block; ...

Comment: ok, that load the overlay perfectly, but now I can't close it. If I click outside the "mask" or on the "close button", it's not closing. Not sure if I need to change JS code for that to work. I originally had the mask to onclick="document.location='#'; for it to close

Answer (score 0):

```
$(".button").click(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();

        $.ajax(function(){
            url: "action.php",
            method: "get",
            data: {
                'id': $(this).attr("data-action")//use single quotes for attribute name
            }, 
            success: openOverlay(data)
        })
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

Pass object to $.ajax method instead of function

Instead of this `$.ajax((function()){`  use `this $.ajax({});`

```
 $.ajax({
         url: 'action.php',
         method:'get',
         data: {
           id: $(this).attr("data-action")
          }, 
          success: openOverlay
          })
```

Comment: its working for me and I am able to use Ajax and get response `This is a TEST...  ID = 3(1)(2)`. I think you have to handle your success response in a proper manner

Comment: yes, the alert works, it was a problem with  $("#overlay").css("display", 'block').css("opacity", '1');  $("#mask").css("display", 'block').css("opacity", '1');  Thanks for the help

Answer (score 0):

Try with this you will get result what you want !!!

Remove other overlay function only below java script code is enough.

```js
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(".button").click(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();

        $.ajax({
            url: "action.php",
            data: {
    id:$(this).attr("data-action")
    }, 
            type: "GET",
            success: function(html_content){
     $("#overlay-content").html("");

    // Add new stuff in
    $("#overlay-content").html(html_content);

    // this is your code $("#overlay").css("display:block; opacity:1;");
    // u need to write like this -below like this 
    $("#overlay").css("display","block");
    
    $("#mask").css("display","block");
    console.log(html_content);
   }
   
        });
    });
</script>
```